# Storing values of string array in variables in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am very new to java.
I have string array,words[i].
How can i store the each value as a variable instantaneously?

Comment: *How can i store the each value as a variable instantaneously?* : What does that mean ?

Comment: Please grab a book on Java, read it and do some practice. In its current form, I barely understand your question, what do you need?

Comment: They all already are variables by the nature of them being in your array words.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: You can use words[i] as a variable.

Comment: `words[i]` is a variable in itself ! You can access each element using index , as `words[0], words[1]...`

Comment: Thanks guys.i need to send this array to another class.How can i perform a for loop on this array send each value.

Comment: You just pass the whole array to another class. You may also want to pass array.clone().

Comment: You need to send the entire array or individual words to another class?

Comment: thanks,previously,i have sent a string str as here.How can i send words[i] instead of str to another class. Cursor testdata = TA.getTestData(str);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have your values stored as variables, they are called :

```
word[0]
word[1]
word[2]
word[3]
word[4]
word[5]
```

…

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access any of the words in the array, then you can do so. You do not need to give them all variable names. For instance, say you have your words array.
To print the 3rd word in the word array to the console:

```
System.out.println(words[2]);
```

Noting that the first element in an array is element 0.